# Google chrome lock in fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome

I have a web application (directory slides) program which is preferable to run in fullscreen on `google chrome`. Now the problem is i would like to limit the user access to the browsers functionality so when the browser is in fullscreen i would like to lock it.

Is there any way to do these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally referred to as "Kiosk mode," and Chrome does appear to support it. From https://lifehacker.com/use-chromes-kiosk-mode-to-limit-someones-access-to-yo-1243433249:

1. Open up Chrome's settings.
2. Under "Users" click "Add new user."
3. Give the new profile a name and picture. Make sure "Create a desktop shortcut for this user" is checked. Click "Create."
4. Right-click the newly-created shortcut and select "Properties."
5. In the "Target" field, add "--kiosk" (no quotes) to the end.
6. Click "Apply."

Comment: Yes it helped alot!

Comment: @acy You are correct, although the general process is the same on any other platform (start Chrome with the --kiosk flag). I just confirmed this works on my Linux system by running `google-chrome --kiosk https://example.com/` (make sure you don't have any other Chrome windows open, otherwise it'll just open a new tab). You haven't mentioned what non-Windows OS you're using, but if you need help modifying desktop shortcuts you might want to check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ since this isn't really a programming question.